# I want to read all txt/csv /xml files from a folder and save it to my SQL database - C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, csv

What is the best approach of reading the lines of each document in a specified folder, add the data to my model and then save it to my database.

I have multiple txt/csv/xml files looking like this in a folder called "my-folder" that's within the project.

| CustomerNumber | ProductNumber | Quantity | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17890 | 123451324A | 1 | CowShoe |
| 17890 | 4000-AAA | 2 | HorseShoe |
| 17890 | 4000-BAA | 2 | PigShoe |
| 17890 | 4000-CAA | 8 | BirdShoe |

My model class looks like this

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductNumber { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm also wondering how I should handle the fact that I only want the data to be saved to the database once when the application is started, meaning rerunning the application shouldn't create more rows in the database from files already read.

Comment: Just start coding is a possibility, read the files, store the name of the files you've read so you don't need to process them again when the app starts. Once you have that you can add new features.

Comment: I like the comment from @PeterBons and would like to also add that, try all your explorations to find the possibilities of reading them and as a learning, add elapsed time for each solution. Look for the ideal one from your exploration.

Comment: @PeterBons Hi thanks for taking your time to answer, i probably explained my problem abit bad im sorry. The problem i have isn't really how to read the files from the folder orthe lines in the files, it's more how do i diffrentiate the "Header" aka the first row in the file (|CustomerNumber|ProductNumber|Quantity|Name|) from the other lines, and then add the data to the model accordingly

Comment: If you're using a library most of them have an option to skip the first row. If you read them yourself just skip the first row if that row contains headers. If the first row contains headers search for the name of the property in the cells and you will know what column belongs to what property assuming headers have the same names as the model properties

Comment: pls take a look ChoETL library, to read such files in different formats. https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL

Comment: Cinchoo it would perhaps be better to declare your affiliation, even in a comment, such as "I am the maintainer of a library that can do this; see it at.."